# Render and Constructor in react-native ordering console.log

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm having a little difficulty understanding the flow of the program in this react native app.

I have put console.log statements through out the app, to try to understand.

So I initialise the state in the constructor to lat: 0, long: 0, err: null and markers: []. Then in the constructor I call my API method to get all the locations and populate the markers method. The output from the prints is as follows:

//From the render method

```js
[]
[]
[]
```

//Then the constructor async method returns and we set the markers

```js
{markers: [{title: "A", coordinate: {latitude: 0, longitude: 1}, description: "abc"},
{title: "B", coordinate: {latitude: 0, longitude: 1}, description: "abc"}]}
```

I then call the render method, I understand this is probably terrible practice but it was simply to try to debug, hoping that the markers would then be visible on the map.

However, after this, the render method continues to print [], which seems really weird to me, since I've just set it in the constructor!

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
});

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0,
      error: null,
      markers: []
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.state = {
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        };
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
      );
    fetch(API_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        var relevantLocations = []
        for (var i = 0; i < responseJson.length; i++) {
          var location = responseJson[i];
          relevantLocations.push({
            title: location.name,
            coordinate: {latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude},
            description: "test" + i
          });
        }
        console.log("Setting state");
        this.state = {
          markers: relevantLocations
        };
        console.log(this.state);
        this.render();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  onRegionChange = (region) => {
    this.setState({ region });
  }

  onPress = () => {
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.markers);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView style={styles.map}
          onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
          onPress={this.onPress}
        >
        {this.state.markers.map(marker => {
            return <MapView.Marker
              key={marker}
              coordinate={marker.coordinate}
              title={marker.title}
              description={marker.description}
            />
          })}
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

How is it that the variables I'm setting in the constructor are being overwritten?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, asynchronous calls in React are placed in the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method, which gets invoked immediately after the initial call to `render()`. The `constructor` is for initialization, i.e. initializing component `state`, calling `super` on any `props` passed in, `bind`ing component methods. I would move all of your async calls, including the call to `navigator` and `fetchAPI` into `componentDidMount` and ensure that whatever `state` you initialize will not cause any errors on `render`. As Tyler McGinnis writes in [this post](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-interview-questions/):

> AJAX requests should go in the componentDidMount lifecycle event.
>
> There are a few reasons for this,
>
> Fiber, the next implementation of React’s reconciliation algorithm, will have the ability to start and stop rendering as needed for performance benefits. One of the trade-offs of this is that componentWillMount, the other lifecycle event where it might make sense to make an AJAX request, will be “non-deterministic”. What this means is that React may start calling componentWillMount at various times whenever it feels like it needs to. This would obviously be a bad formula for AJAX requests.
>
> You can’t guarantee the AJAX request won’t resolve before the component mounts. If it did, that would mean that you’d be trying to setState on an unmounted component, which not only won’t work, but React will yell at you for. Doing AJAX in componentDidMount will guarantee that there’s a component to update.

Here's a full reworked example using `componentDidMount` and setting `state` properly after all async requests have resolved.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
});

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0,
      error: null,
      markers: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        
        fetch(API_URL)
           .then((response) => response.json())
           .then((responseJson) => {
              var relevantLocations = []
              for (var i = 0; i < responseJson.length; i++) {
                var location = responseJson[i];
                relevantLocations.push({
                  title: location.name,
                  coordinate: {latitude: location.latitude, longitude: 
                    location.longitude},
                  description: "test" + i
                });
              }
             console.log("Setting state");
             this.setState({
                ...this.state
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                markers: relevantLocations
             });
           })
           .catch((error) => {
             console.error(error);
           });

       },
      (error) => this.setState({ ...this.state, error: error.message }),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
      );

    
  }

  onRegionChange = (region) => {
    this.setState({ region });
  }

  onPress = () => {
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.markers);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView style={styles.map}
          onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
          onPress={this.onPress}
        >
        {this.state.markers.map(marker => {
            return <MapView.Marker
              key={marker}
              coordinate={marker.coordinate}
              title={marker.title}
              description={marker.description}
            />
          })}
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It also appears you are explicitly trying to reset the value of `state` several times in your `constructor`, which is an anti-pattern. You should call `this.state` **once** in your `constructor` to initialize `state` and then use `setState` in your other component methods to actually update the the state.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. About to give it a go now, and will let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Parker, thanks for the advice. It did seem strange setting the state several times, even though it was for different properties. Thanks a lot as well, I will try that.

Comment: One more thing I noticed. When you are calling `setState` you need to be sure to copy **all** the properties of `state`. A lot of folks use the `spread` operator `...` to do this like so: `this.setState({ ...this.state, markers: response.data });` What you're saying with a statement like this is "Copy over all properties of `state` except for the `markers` property, which I want to mutate to be assigned to `response.data`. If you don't copy over properties, your new `state` object will **only** have those properties you passed it.

Comment: Ah! perfect! Thanks a lot for that tip too!

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks a lot for the help. That's fixed it! Something I've been stuck on for the whole day! Really really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to hear it!